# google places api returning null results

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-api, xamarin, google-places

I am developing an app for ios and I'm am using the Google places api. When I make my request, I am getting a response, status reads "Ok", but every attribute is null. Interesting thing is that for different searches, I get a unique number of results, and the same number of unique lat, lng attributes. Just everything else(name, formatted address,etc...) all return null. I've searched but can find no reason for this. Anybody else have experience with this issue or maybe an idea to correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out, in my url I was using "radarsearch", where i should have been using "nearbysearch". Thanks!